# Browser timeout when service takes long time to respond

Tags: javascript, angularjs, web-services

I have REST API which process bulk data. Since it is taking long time browser is getting timed out without accepting response.

Service is running properly I have checked in logs.

PS : I am using REST API and angular js.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: You have to inform the user when the process finishes by another method; for example sending an email.

Comment: Cant we accept response on UI front overriding browser timeout?

Comment: Maybe you can but the most common way to handle long processes is to inform user after the job finish asynchronously. Because, even if you can override the timeout, the browser may fail during that time and the response can be missed anyway.

Comment: But that won't help in my case because I have some run time data validations also :(

Comment: What kind of validations? Is it separated from the main process or something?

Comment: Consider running the task in server on a timer and write the result in db/file, when user request, show the last result along with last updated date.

Comment: Yes, and also you can set a js timeout function that checks per 100ms if the db is set, pass the id to js via ajax before running timeout function

Comment: Guys I want response on UI since I need to show result to the user..@Icycool : Its not one time of a day it can happen multiple times as it is a user action.